# Where to place data-formatting to display in UI using a ViewModel and Clean Code?

Tags: android, mvvm, clean-architecture

I have some data contained in an entity class retrieved from an API, but I need to format this data to update the UI. The problem is I need the App Context to do it, specifically to access resources like drawables and strings.

If I want to use the View just to paint the UI, I should place these formattings in the ViewModel (or inside an auxiliary method called from there), but this forces me to inject the Context into the ViewModel which makes the testing trickier.

Therefore, what should be the best approach here?

1- All formattings located in the View and keep the ViewModel isolated from Context and use Unit Tests for it.

or

2- Find a safe way to inject Context in ViewModel to make there the formattings and use Instrumented Tests instead.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping the view as simple as possible and put formatting code into the ViewModel.

In order to keep the ViewModel independent from the concrete Context (e.g. for testability reasons) I would recommend adapter pattern. Create an interface which provided exactly the functionality you need and use this in your ViewModel. Provide an "adapter" around the original context which implements this interface.
For your tests use a different implementation (dynamic mock?) of that interface.

Comment: But the Adapter approach only works with Dependency Injection right? 

Because, as I see, if you use a Service Locator, you also need to pass the Context to the Adapter through the ViewModel.

Comment: You would need some way to decide which adapter implementation should be used. Dependency injection containers would be one, but also ServiceLocators usually support registration of different types for an interface